# Remove duplicates from table which doesn't have any key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have 2 tables TabA and TabB. Both don't have any key columns.

Column wise both are replica and have more than 80 columns.

TabA has 30 million records. TabB has 2000 records only.

Now I need to compare all the columns between both tables since NO key column is there and remove duplicate records from TabA.

I would like to find best approach to compare both tables instead of placing all 80 columns either in JOINS or WHERE clause.

Comment: Are  there any Unique Identifiers in both tables? what have you tried so far, can you show us that code?

Comment: Hi Otter, Thank you for looking into this. Its a log table that we are ETLing from source server. Due to some bug in ETL, We got duplicate records into target. Now we fixed the actual bug in ETL. However now we need to remove the duplicates from Target. We have requested the source db development team for unique records and they provided few columns as unique, but when we compare them with target we found again duplicates with some more columns. So we decided to compare all the columns and looking forward a solution to compare all the columns in a best approach.

Comment: Pro tip: Many people outside India don't know what crore is. I personally had to google it, and I'll bet I'm not the only one - so not everyone will understand what's 3 crore. However, Every English reader can understand 30 millions, or even 30,000,000.

Comment: The best approach would be to try and identify the natural key of these tables. Hopefully, it's not table-wide but only spans over a few columns. If that's not the case, you're in for a hard time.

Comment: Hi Zohar, Thank you. Updated as 30 million recordsand if there is no better solution to compare all the columns then I shall go with identifying natural keys.

Comment: So why have you not discarded what you imported and simply re-started the import process? Why waste time and effort trying to overcome a problem that has been fixed? And if you are concerned about "duplicates", then why are you not enforcing uniqueness at the appropriate level in your destination table to **prevent** the problem? This is but one reason why you should think carefully about intentionally duplicating data - especially between 2 different "systems".

Comment: Hi SMor, Thank you. We have already added the Re-ETL of the table approach in our solution list. However this needs to be done in multiple customers. So that we are trying to provide script to remove the duplicates as first thing. If couldn't then we will suggest to re-ETL the table.

Answer (score 0):

If all 80 columns are needed to identify the record, you'd have a hard time not using all of them in your query, one way or another.

You could calculate a hashcode using `HASHBYTES()` on all the columns, and then compare only the resulting hashcode.

There's also `CHECKSUM(*)` function that calculates hash on all the columns, without the need to explicitly list them, but it returns `int` as a result, which is too weak if false positives now and then are not acceptable.